# Mysql change default table charset to database charset

Tags: mysql

I have problem with mysql table charset. Every table in my database has default charset. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE privacy_settings (
  id_privacy_setting int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_account int(11) NOT NULL,
  setting_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  privacy_level int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id_privacy_setting),
  KEY fk_privacy_settings_accounts (id_account),
  CONSTRAINT fk_privacy_settings_accounts FOREIGN KEY (id_account) REFERENCES accounts (id_account) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to remove DEFAULT CHARSET block, so table could use database default charset:

```
CREATE TABLE privacy_settings (
      id_privacy_setting int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      id_account int(11) NOT NULL,
      setting_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      privacy_level int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (id_privacy_setting),
      KEY fk_privacy_settings_accounts (id_account),
      CONSTRAINT fk_privacy_settings_accounts FOREIGN KEY (id_account) REFERENCES accounts (id_account) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Is there any way to do this without recreating the table?

Answer (score 11):

To change a table's character set, from [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

If you want to change the table default character set and all character columns (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT) to a new character set, use a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

---

If you want to convert an entire database to use a different default character set, you can issue this statement: (from [Default Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html))

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Comment: I know, but when I do so, `DEFAULT CHARSET` block is not removed from my table definition

Comment: You may want to change the entire database then. I've added more info to the answer. I suspect that the default charset and the active charset may be different for your table, but it depends on how you are generating the definition. `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` should work. After I execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement to change the character set, the `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` query shows the new character set as the DEFAULT CHARSET. To get a list of charsets/collations, use [`SHOW COLLATION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-collation.html).

Comment: I wannt to completely remove DEFAULT CHARSET block from table definition, not to chage default charset for table, but remove this block to make each table to use the database encoding

Comment: I don't believe you can *remove* the default charset. See [9.1.3. Specifying Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-syntax.html) for more info, sorry I'm not sure what else to recommend.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to change collation and default character set for tables and schemas:

```
alter table TABLENAME convert to CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
alter database SCHEMA default character set utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```