# phpmyadmin change the char_set of existing table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I change the CHAR_SET of an existing database/table in phpmyadmin ?

The collation of tables can be changed by clicking the table name -> operations 
but I did not find how to change the CHAR_SET

I am trying to export a 5.5 database with utf8mb4 to a 5.0 database (no utf8mb4)

best regards

for people having the same problem here is a post [that has the SQL solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028610/mysql-change-default-table-charset-to-database-charset)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql change default table charset to database charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028610/mysql-change-default-table-charset-to-database-charset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the table `default character set` to a new character set, use a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

So query will be:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Font: [How to change the default charset of a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906813/how-to-change-the-default-charset-of-a-mysql-table)

In PHPMyadmin:

You need to go to phpmyadmin > information_schema > schemata > change your DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME with query

Font: [Change default Charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773488/change-default-charset)

Comment: my question was if it is possible to do this IN phpmyadmin.
Your answer is just a copy paste of the post to which I linked.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where I can find the informaration. But it seems that it is not possible to do this in the gui in phpmyadmin. It is only possible to do this using a SQL query. Thank you now I know and I don't have to look any further.

Comment: This is the correct answer
Stating that it cant be done "IN phpmyadmin" is kind of disingenous as there is a built in SQL query window.